# How to start multiple instances of the same Java project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing nodes which should simulate UDP communication in between themselves.
It should be possible that these nodes are started on different computers, so i'm interested in how could i test this the easiest on my computer.
So what i need specifically need is how to start the same project in Eclipse multiple times, possibly with different command line arguments.

Comment: you can start one more instance of eclipse and open the same project (maybe you would like to copy it to your new workspace). or you can execute the application twice from `cmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line arguments are stored in Eclipse in a Run Configuration (menu: `Run` > `Run Configurations...`, or `Run` > `Debug Configurations...`).

Just create two of them, reference the same `main` class, and specify different command line arguments, e.g. to specify different ports, then `Run`/`Debug` both of them.

No need for two Eclipse instances. You can easily have many running programs, even for the same Run Configuration, assuming they don't conflict on some shared resource like a port.

The `Console` view will keep the output from each running program separate. Use the `Display Selected Console` toolbar pull-down in the upper right of the `Console` view to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can export as runnable jar file and execute it twice by the commands

```
$ java -jar your-jar-file.jar &
$ java -jar your-jar-file.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, there are many ways to start your project instances depends on your project.

But I think the easiest way is as follows.

1. Create two different workspaces and copy same code in both.
2. Create two instances of your server instances.

I think this will work for you.

Comment: If you're going to just make a copy of the program it would be a lot easier to just export the project and run that as many times as you need it to be running since it will open up a new instance every time you run it.